# merge sort is duplicatiing array entries

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to implement in Java the merge sort algorithm according to Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms. The problem with my code (below) is that the main array is duplicating some of its entries during the merge step.

Is someone able to catch what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
  static void merge(int a[], int p, int q, int r)
        {
            int n1 = q - p;
            int n2 = (r - q);
            int [] left = new int[n1 + 1];
            int [] right = new int[n2 + 1];
            int pp = p;
            int qq = q;
            for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            {
                left[i] = a[++pp];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
            {
                right[i] = a[++qq];
            }
            left[left.length-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            right[right.length-1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for(int k = p; k < r; k++)
            {
                if(left[i] <= right[j])
                {
                    a[k] = left[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[k] = right[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        static int [] mergeSort(int a[], int p, int r)
        {
            if(p < r)
            {
                int q = (p + r)/2;
                mergeSort(a, 1, q);
                mergeSort(a, q + 1, r);
                merge(a, p, q, r);
            }
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: It would be better if you went through a debugger, and tried to understand why it doesn't work. You could also search the actual working code on the internet, and compare it to yours to understand what's wrong

Comment: Fun fact: MergeSort can be implemented very cleanly without resorting to recursion and with the allocation of just a single additional array. Check out the Wikipedia page (Bottom-up implementation).

Comment: I feel like `Collections.sort` or something around there would offer the functionality that you're looking for; I know this doesn't answer your question but it's an idea.

Comment: (`merge sort is duplicatiing array entries` moreover, it does seem to affect letter `i` in the title, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue here is the example from the book apparently uses index range from 1 to length. It will be simpler if you change the index range from 0 to length-1, which I assume in the rest of my answer.

Use post increment while copying to left[] and right[] as answered by laune (since index range 0 to length-1).

```
                left[i] = a[pp++];
                ...
                right[i] = a[qq++];
```

The main issue is the merge function is not checking to see if it reached the end of the left or right run during a merge. This can be fixed by changing the inner if to:

```
                if (i < n1 && (j >= n2 || left[i] <= right[j]))
```

The recursive calls to merge sort should be:

```
                mergeSort(a, p, q);
                mergeSort(a, q, r);
```

Not shown, but the initial call to mergeSort should be:

```
                mergeSort(a, 0, a.length);
```

There's no need to allocate the extra element in left and right (since index range is 0 to length-1).

```
            int [] left = new int[n1];
            int [] right = new int[n2];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is in error (as well as its sibling in the next loop):

```
left[i] = a[++pp];
```

You want to copy starting with pp = p, so don't increment before you access the array element:

```
left[i] = a[pp++];
```